# Parse curl response to variable and use it in curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN=$(curl -isX POST 'http://localhost:3005/auth/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "test@test.de",
  "password": "1234"
}' | grep X-Subject-Token | sed "s/X-Subject-Token: //g")

echo $TOKEN

curl --trace test.txt -X POST "http://localhost:3005/v1/users" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "X-Auth-token: $TOKEN" \
        -d '{
                "user": {
                        "username": "alice",
                        "email": "alice@test.com",
                        "password": "test"
                }
        }'
```

The command `echo $TOKEN` is printing the right result (something like 35be3d05-7f80-4b11-ad20-7a7110e9d3a7). From the last curl request I get the following error from curl:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If I write above the last curl request `TOKEN="35be3d05-7f80-4b11-ad20-7a7110e9d3a7"` the request is working. So I guess there is something wrong with the TOKEN variable.

Kindly Regards

EDIT:
Output from `declare -p TOKEN` :

```
"eclare -- TOKEN="6770806a-1230-4f64-b519-1841e9deb5f1
```

Comment: What's output of `declare -p TOKEN`?

Comment: Your token probably has an carriage return appended to it; the command substitution strips the line feed, leaving the carriage return of the CRLF pair that network protocols use to terminate lines.

Comment: @chepner you are right. I had the same idea and removed it. Now I removed it again and now it worked. . . Don't know what I have done wrong at the first time. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove an carriage return. Thanks to @chepner!

Solution:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -isX POST 'http://localhost:3005/auth/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "test@test.de",
  "password": "1234"
}' | grep X-Subject-Token | sed "s/X-Subject-Token: //g" | tr -d '\r')
```